# Setting a drupal entity date field without EMW

Tags: date, drupal-7, entity, metadata, wrapper

Is it possible to set a date field (capturing a start and end time) on a drupal entity WITHOUT using entity metadatawrapper?

with EWM I could do (with a corresponding ->save() after, of course)

```
$wrapper->field_custom_date->set(array(
   'value' => $date_start_value,
   'value2' => $date_end_value,
));
```

I've tried

```
$entity->field_custom_date = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(0 => array(
   'value' => $date_start_value,
   'value2' => $date_start_value,
)));
```

and a few other very similar variations to no avail. I've tried Googling but I can only find solutions and examples using EMW. Is this possible or do I have to use the entity metadata wrapper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$entity->field_custom_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $date_start_value;
$entity->field_custom_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value2'] = $date_end_value;
```